# Inconsistent behavior from ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive

Tags: c#, uwp

I've been trying to get tcp keep alive packets to send using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.  As far as I can see the only way to do this is using `ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, X, Y)`.  When testing this in a LinqPad script I have got it working although it's not consistent.  For example if I do a manual call to `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(myUrl)` before I call `ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive` then it won't work, I assume because of caching, however if it's the first thing that happens it usually works (I'm fairly certain it's still inconsistent here).  Note that I am checking whether it works or not using Wireshark.

However when I try to use this in my real UWP application it fails.  I've tried setting this as the first App.xaml.cs constructor and just before instantiating the `HttpClient` and various places in between without any luck.

Am I missing something?

Note that I realise it is possible to use `HttpWebRequest` directly and set this on it's `ServicePoint` instance but I'd like to know why this isn't working first before resorting to something like this.

EDIT: I ended up trying to implement this with `HttpWebRequest` and `ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive` and while it compiles, it fails when it's called with a `Operation is not supported on this platform` exception.  I guess this means the main problem here might be that UWP just doesn't support sending TCP keep alive packets?

EDIT2: I've created a minimum reproducible example here: https://github.com/csuzw/TcpKeepAliveTest .  In this case the `HttpWebRequest` approach does not fail with the `Operation is not support on this platform` exception but it doesn't send keep alive packets either.  I wonder if the difference is that my real app is a Xamarin.Forms UWP target app, whereas this test app is a straight UWP app.  Regardless both approaches used in this test app fail to produce keep alive packets.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] for more diagnosis?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I've added a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: After checking the APIs in [.NET API Browser for System.Net.ServicePointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=dotnet-uwp-10.0&term=System.Net.ServicePointManager) and [.NET API Browser for ServicePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=dotnet-uwp-10.0&term=ServicePoint). They're all not supported in UWP.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Does this mean there is no way to send tcp keep alive packets when making http requests in UWP?

Comment: There's a [StreamSocketListenerControl.KeepAlive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistenercontrol.keepalive) property for `StreamSocket` object. Please try to use `StreamSocket` to do TCP request.